# Windows Service Setup & Deployment Issues

Tags: .net, windows-services, setup-deployment

I'm having a problem installing a windows service using the Setup & Deployment Method listed on the msdn website.

Here's what i did.

- I created a dummy windows service.
- I then created an projectInstaller for that service by right clicking on my service in design mode and choosing add an installer.
- After that i created a separate Setup & Deployment project within the same solution and added output as the Windows Service Project.

When i right click on the Setup & Deployment project and hit install, the installer runs through the setup process and says the installation has completed successfully.
Now when i go to the services windows in administration  for some reason i don't see the Installed service listed at all.
Has anyone run into this before? If so do you know what i might be doing wrong and how i can correct this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you define the Custom actions?
Have a look at this page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421

Make sure you don't forget step 3 under *Use a compiled Setup project to install the Windows Service*

Comment: +1 for the link; this article has since been superseded by http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169